# Non-integer counter for do ... until loop in bash

Tags: bash

I'm currently using bash 3.2.51

I'm trying to create a simple do until loop that steps up in small intervals of 0.05. My current code is shown below, it works fine for whole numbers but when I use non-integer it fails with errors.

```
x=0.05
until [ $x -gt 1.20 ]
do
//some code //
x =$((x+0.05))
done
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `seq 0.05 0.05 1.20 `

Comment: If it's possible giving your needed precision, etc., it may be worth converting to integers.  (Change 0.05 to 5, 1.20 to 120, etc.)

Comment: spelling and phrasing

Answer (score 0):

`bash` currently doesnt support `float` variables, you need to delegate the task to other programs.

```
$echo $((1+0.05))
bash: 1+0.05: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".05")
$ echo $(echo "1+0.05" | bc -l)
1.05
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
```

more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks